# Can't get different element when maping tab for my component

Tags: react-native, components

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text> Entrées</Text>
    <EntréesList token={token} entrées={menu.id_entree}/>
</View>
```

EntréesList Component

```
<Content>
    <List>
      {
        this.props.entrées && this.props.entrées.map(obj => {
            return(
                <EntréesDetail token={token} entrées={obj} key={obj}/>
            )
        })
      }
    </List>
  </Content>
```

EntréesDetail component

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getEntrées({entrées: this.props.entrées, token: this.props.token}))
}

render() {

    return (
       <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Card style={styles.card}>
      <CardItem >
        <Image style={styles.img} source={require('../../assets/repas-min.jpg')}/>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.name}>  {this.props.entrée.name} </Text>
          <Text note numberOfLines={1} style={styles.price}> €</Text>
        </View>
      </CardItem>
    </Card> 
  </View>
    )}
}



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        error: state.entrées.oneError,
        loading: state.entrées.oneloading,
        entrée: state.entrées.oneEntrées
}
```

I tried to have all the different names in different component. But the display print them quickly and then only the last name is seen on all the component

Comment: try to explain step by step in your question what you are having problem ???

Comment: so i got this list of entries. i map that list and then render a component (component detail). In that component i do dispatch get the result and print it. But only the last is pritn in every component. The orthers are print pretty quicly

Comment: <EntréesList token={token} entrées={menu.id_entree}/>  are you sure you are passing list of your entrees array here ???

Comment: yes. i printed it and it's corrected

Comment: i have some questions give me answer step by step. ok

Comment: Okey i'll respond the best